# Complicated sorting of mysql result

Tags: mysql, sorting

I wonder if its possible to sort a result so that if a column contains a spesific word ('misc'), it will come out last?

current query:

```
select * from table order by name asc
```

current result:

```
banjo
guitar
miscproduct1
miscproduct2
piano
```

pseudocode:

```
select * from table order by name asc, 
except if name like '%misc%' then sort it last
```

pseudo result:

```
banjo
guitar
piano
miscproduct1
miscproduct2
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Sort first by `if contains misc = 1 else 0` _then_ sort by name.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: @KristianRafteseth I think Boris said `SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY IF(name LIKE '%misc%', 1, 0), name`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`LOCATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) as the first ordering argument:

```
ORDER BY LOCATE('misc', name), name;
```

The `LOCATE()` function returns `0` if the search string can't be found in the subject, and yields a positive integer if it is found.

To normalize the sorting for subjects that contain the search you can combine with `LEAST()`:

```
ORDER BY LEAST(LOCATE('misc', name), 1), name;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a CASE in the ORDER BY clause.

```
SELECT colName
FROM table
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN colName LIKE 'misc%' 
    THEN concat('zzz',colName) 
    ELSE colName 
  END
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e08c/7